# Find the position of an int value in a 2D int array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write a methode which will return the 1st position of a certain value in an 2D int array. If the value is not in the array, then the posistion will be an array with values [-1, -1]

My code is:

```
public static int[] findItemIn2DArray(int[][] A, int value) 
{
    int position[] = new int [] {-1, -1} ;
    
    for (int i=0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < (A[i].length/2)+1; j++)
        {
            if ( A[i][j] == value ) 
            {
                position [0] = i;
                position [1] = j;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    
    return position;
}
```

I give the array

```
int numbers[][] = 
        
            {
                {2,3,5}         , 
                {4,1,0,10}      ,
                {3,9,10}        ,
                {5,9,10,1,12}
            };
```

and I'm searching for the value 10.

It was supposed to return [1,3], but instead I get [-1,-1]. I think that it does not go through all the row, but only checks out the first value.

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you only search half the "embedded" array? Seems like some simple debugging or logging would clear this up almost immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to iterate through the whole column, not only half of it (in your second for-loop).

Second, your first `break` statement should be INSIDE the if statement, since the way you have your code now, your program will always break out of the code without getting to all the elements.

Third, Why do you have a second `break`? That causes your code to break every time you only get through the first row. You don't need it there.

Your code should look like:

```
public static int[] findItemIn2DArray(int[][] A, int value) 
{
int position[] = new int [] {-1, -1} ;

boolean found = false;
for (int i=0; i < A.length; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j < (A[i].length); j++)
    {
        if ( A[i][j] == value ) 
        {
            position [0] = i;
            position [1] = j;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found)
        break;
}

return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the first occurrence isnt equal to the value, it breaks the loop straight away. Try moving the break statement inside the 'if' statement

Answer (score 0):

it's because you break the outer for loop after the inner for loop

Answer (score 0):

The (A[i].length/2)+1 was a typo, it sould be A[i].length instead (that's what happens when you use CNTL+C without checking!)

The comments about the break command were very usefull, thank you all!